# Move pictures into folders based on Creation Date

Tags: r

I want to catalog a bunch of pictures from a source folder and move them based on their creation date.  So, if a file was created on 2017-10-31, it would move the picture to a parent folder of 2017 and into the "2017-10-31" sub-folder.  If the folder does not exist, then it should create it.

i used the below to create a data listing of the files creation dates and year.

```
files_tmp <- dir("C:/Users/.../pictures/", 
  full.names = TRUE)

filedate <- 
  as.data.frame(file.info(files_tmp)$ctime)
  names(filedate)[1] <- "date"

pics <- filedate %>% 
  mutate (createDate = format(date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
  year = format(date, "%Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your data correctly. Moving the files to appropriate folders is then trivial. See comments in the code.

```
# create some fake data
cat("2017-01-01", file = "2017-01-01.txt")
cat("2018-05-11", file = "2018-05-11.txt")
cat("2018-09-09", file = "2018-09-09.txt")

# fetch all files - here I'm using to find exact dates and your method may vary
xy <- list.files(pattern = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\.txt")

# prepare variables that will create (sub)folders
# having things in Date form makes extraction of year easy (and safe)
xy <- data.frame(file = xy, date = as.Date(gsub("\\.txt", "", xy)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xy$path <- sprintf("./%s/%s", format(xy$date, "%Y"), xy$date)

# check that folder(s) exist
subfolders <- as.character(unique(xy$path))
# create those that do not exist
cs <- xy[!sapply(subfolders, FUN = dir.exists), ]
# if there's no data, it means all appropriate folders are already created
if (nrow(cs) == 0) {
  message("All folders already exist.")
} else {
  sapply(cs$path, dir.create, recursive = TRUE)
}

# prepare paths where to move files to
xy$dest_to <- sprintf("%s/%s", xy$path, xy$file)

# execute the final move
mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
  message(sprintf("Moving file %s to %s", x, y))
  file.rename(from = x, to = y)
}, x = xy$file, y = xy$dest_to)
```

Comment: thanks!  This worked for the most part.  I was having issues with file.rename, but used file.copy instead.